# Field of view typescript

Tags: typescript, view

I had class with variable

```
export class HomePage{
   portals:any;
   public goToReport{
      this.portals=11; //All work great
      function changePortal(){
         this.portals = 12; //not work
         return this.portals;
      }
      let callIt = changePortal();
      console.log(callIt); //undefined
   }
}
```

How i can edit value of this variable inside function if i initialize it inside class?

Comment: Define "not work". You define a function, but you never call it anywhere. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @JBNizet I edit question. But its doesnt work not because it

Comment: You need to bind the function to this. Or to use an arrow function, which does that automatically. This question is beaing asked every other day

Comment: @JBNizet iam so sorry. Iam newbee in typescript and oop programming. Can you give me some example or some link?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: @JBNizet thank you so much